What is frame/render graph?
Could somebody explain to me what a render/frame graph is? I am faimiliar with rendering pipeline in DX11/DX12 on a basic level, but I could not find any solid and readable info on frame graph.
I have looked through some GDC notes on the subject, but they are pretty incomprehensible for a beginner like me, so I would like to see some elemental explanation, if possible. Thanks in advice.
